# How to make code with setTimeout work correct?

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

This code display 10 ten times.

But I want to display numbers from 0 to 9.

How can I fix this code?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);  
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate. This should answer your question: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)